# If the degree of $(f(x)+f(−x))$ is $10$, then the degree of $(g(x)−g(−x))$ is?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial and $g(x) = f'(x)$ be its derivative. If the degree of $(f(x)+f(−x))$ is $10$, then the degree of $(g(x)−g(−x))$ is______?

---

My attempt :

Somewhere the answer is given as $9$.

IMO, when we derivative a polynomial function, it reduces the degree by one. The same function is added, which cannot increase the degree of the resulting function, but it can reduce the degree when we subtract it. So, it should be maximum $9$.

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sentence "when we derivative a polynomial function, it reduced degree by one" is mathematically correct (if your polynomial is non constant).

To see why this is true, take $P(X)=a_nX^n +a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1X + a_0 \in \Bbb R[X]$ your favorite polynomial ($a_n≠0,n≥1$).
Its derivative is $P'(X)=na_nX^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1$. Since $n\cdot a_n ≠0$, you see that the degree of $P'(X)$ is exactly $n-1$.

Then, apply this to $f(x)+f(−x)$. What is its derivative?

> It is precisely $g(x)-g(-x)$... whose degree is $9$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$F(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$$,
We see, here, g(x) = f'(x)
$$F'(x) = f'(x) + f'(-x) (-x)' = g(x) - g(-x)$$

So F'(x) has order of one less of F(x).